# how can I prevent multiple clicks on the links

Tags: jquery

I have few database records displaying in a table formate on the web page. Each record/row has action links as "view", "Edit" and other links. As soon as I click on "Edit" link of the 1st record, i would like to disable all the other links on the page to prevent multiple clicks on the page until the action completed. once after page reload back i would like to show all the links enable again. Please suggest any jquery soluction. (I can have one/same class name for all the links if needed)

The problem is when the user click on "Edit" link of the any single record, the page (java form/request) submit and do some database updates and do some background process and again loading the same page back with some update data, which takes few seconds. when the user click on "Edit" link of the 1st record, he is not waiting until the process completes and page loads, he immediately clicking on multiple edit links, which causing the problem backend some deadlocks, or interrupting another process to finish.

appreciate your help.

--------------------updated -----------------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.xlinks').prop('disabled', false);
    $(".xlinks").click(function() {
        $('.xlinks').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

below 3 links display for each database record, for example if i have 5 records/rows to show then each row display at the end with these View, ViewAndSave and Complete links.

```
<html:link class="xlinks" url="xxx.do" text="view" />
<html:link class="xlinks" url="xxx.do" text="viewAndSave" />
------

<html:link class="xlinks" url="xxx.do" text="Complete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to complete')" />
```

when i click on any one view link all remaining 'view' and 'viewAndSave' links disabled but all Complete links not get disabled.

Comment: Please show us what code you have tried.

Comment: Use something like $('a').prop('disabled',true') as the very code of the link event, then wait for a response (AJAX/something from the server) and then when you get a response, use $('a').prop('disabled',false) to enable all the links again.

Comment: @Michael : i have other functions which im calling like ...onclick=return confirm('xxx') on few links, which is conflicting with disabling these few links. any idea to solve?

Comment: Use proper selectors to not include those links in the jQuery.  Something like $('a:not(.conflict)').prop('disabled',true) or whatever the selector that will remove those links you don't want disabled.

Comment: I want to disable those too

Comment: Can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net to show me what you're talking about?

Comment: @Michael..I updated the post with code snippet.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks Mike for the prop method, initally i forgot to add class name on one of the links so It did not work. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('yourbutton').click(function() {
    $('.otherbuttons').attr('disabled', true);
    //do other functions
});
```

**OR**

```
   $('yourbutton').click(function() {
        $('.otherbuttons').prop('disabled', true);
        //do other functions
    });
```

Since you didn't give any code for us to explore, it's the closest I can get to help you out.

That should help you out, leave some feedback!

Comment: i have other functions which im calling like ...onclick=return confirm('xxx') on few links, which is conflicting with disabling these few links. any idea to solve?

Comment: If I were you, I would start using them on jQuery instead of having them in HTML with onclick events.

Comment: Instead of using onclick="insertfunction" you can create those events on jQuery. for example $('link').click(function(){//insertcodehere}); link is just an example, you can put any DOM element inside $(). I recommend you going to http://www.codecademy.com, there's a good tutorial for beginners in there for jQuery, you should easily get the hang of it!

Comment: :Thanks Rui Silva for the prop method, initally i forgot to add class name on one of the links so It did not work. Now it is working fine.

Comment: A pleasure to help! Be sure to check out codeacademy to improve your skills. I've done pretty much every course in there, it helps you out!